# How to remove two sprites in COCOS2d v3.x in ios

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm working with the cocos2d 3.x and Xcode 5.1.1.I'm doing a game like candy crush here 
i save the sprites in a array while loading,I compare the touched sprite, previous sprite and swap that sprites,now i want to remove these two sprites?
By the following line i removed the last touched sprite..
    [self removeChild:startSprite cleanup:YES];

Comment: Have you tried [sprite removeFromParent] ?

Comment: Yes i tried it also remove the last one,i need to remove the last touched sprite and previous sprite from array

Answer (score 1):

As LearnCocos2D says, you would call this to remove the sprite from the scene (this is more for the benefit of others since you know this):

```
[sprite removeFromParent];
```

Or as you have it you could also remove the child via its parent (this is more for the benefit of others since you know this):

```
[self removeChild:sprite cleanup:YES];
```

To remove it from your array you could simply do this:

```
[array removeObject:sprite];
```

Or if you only knew the array index the sprite was in the array you could use:

```
[array removeObjectAtIndex:index];
```

Note that your array must be an NSMutableArray to use these remove methods.